# Setting up GCM for iOS

Tags: ios, google-cloud-messaging

I have a mobile app created with Phonegap Build which can run on both Android and iOS. I use ASP.NET to set up notifications by calling Google Cloud Messaging. My question is independent of these technologies though. I have tried to read all the GCM documentation, but it doesn't seem written for a newcomer, and I am not using CocoaPods or the other client-side technologies they mention.

I have set up GCM to send notifications to the Android version of my app with no problems; it work when I install the development .apk file directly on my Android tablet, and the exact same HTTP/JSON call works when I'm running the production version installed from Google Play.

As usual, iOS is a whole different world of pain. I believe I have created the APNS certificate correctly using the Apple website. I've uploaded the resulting .p12 file to Google. I can see the token which my app sends to my website, just like I can with an Android device. I plug this token into my server-side code which talks to Google, but I get:

> HTTP return code is 200
>   {"multicast_id":6487xxxxxxx91167,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"InvalidRegistration"}]}

The GCM documentation merely suggests I've got the token wrong. I don't see how as I'm getting a value passed from my app (when it first loads up) to my server and all seems well.

**Thought 1.** Token might be truncated? Android tokens have all been 162 chars long, but the one sent from my iPad was 64 chars long.

**Thought 2.** I wonder if I am using the correct URL; is it `https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send` just like it is for Android devices? And is there a different value needed for Development/Production?

**Thought 3.** How goes Google know whether to use the Development of Production version of my APNS certificate? After all, I uploaded two .p12 files, but my ASP.NET code is only passing my 40 char GCM API key, and the device token.

**Thought 4.** Maybe I made a mess with the Apple certificate process. Would this cause an `InvalidRegistration` error though?

Comment: Are you using the CloudMessaging SDK from Google?

Comment: No I'm not using that, unless the Phonegap plugin https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push does so. I confess I haven't seen the phrase "SDK" used anywhere so far.

Comment: Are sending the actual APNS token received upon registration from the app itself, or exchanging that token with the GCM API for a GCM token?

Comment: My own client-side code obtains the token value from the plugin (which is specifically built for GCM) and sends it to my server. I use that when making the HTTP call to GCM. I have not heard mention of exchanging an iOS token for a GCM token!

Comment: That's where I guess your implementation is failing. In native iOS implementation, the GCM SDK is used to exchange the iOS notification token in exchange for one which can be used by GCM. That is then pushed to our server, which uses the same in any 'send' calls to GCM. Have a look here: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/pull/282

Comment: You must be right. I would be leaping around in joy if only the documentation mentioned this clearly! One obstacle, I guess, is that I'm using Phonegap and not Eclipse/Swift/Xcode/CocoaPods. I did read the link you suggested, very carefully. I cannot see where the plugin exposes a method to perform this 'exchange'. (Or it may be I simply need to convert the 64 chars of hex into a 162 char alphanumeric?) I am really grateful for your help so far...thank you....and if you have any other thoughts I'd be mega grateful!